# Keycloak, Spring Boot, Svelte - CORS

Tags: spring-boot, cors, keycloak

Keycloak: port:8080

Spring Boot: port 8081

Svelte: port: 5173

I'm writing a CRUD application in Spring Boot.
When I call backend (http://localhost:8081/swagger-ui/index.html) everything works fine: I need to log into to the application and I can call all API methods.
Then i decided to add frontend: http://localhost:5173 works, but when I call http://localhost:5173/price-lists, which should call GET Method I get error:

`"Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at 'http://localhost:8081/api/v1/pricelists?page=0&size=100'. (Reason: missing CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'). Status code: 401."`

[image: network]

**Configuration classes:**

```
@EnableWebMvc
public class CorsConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**")
                .allowedOrigins("http://localhost:5173", "http://localhost:8081")
                .allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "OPTIONS")
                .allowedHeaders("*");
    }
}
```

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    private final KeycloakLogoutHandler keycloakLogoutHandler;

    public SecurityConfig(KeycloakLogoutHandler keycloakLogoutHandler) {
        this.keycloakLogoutHandler = keycloakLogoutHandler;
    }

    @Bean
    protected SessionAuthenticationStrategy sessionAuthenticationStrategy() {
        return new RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy(new SessionRegistryImpl());
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain resourceFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/**")
                .hasRole("USER")
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .csrf()
                .disable();

        http.headers().frameOptions().disable();

        http.oauth2Login()
            .and()
            .logout()
            .addLogoutHandler(keycloakLogoutHandler)
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/");

        http.oauth2ResourceServer(OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer::jwt);
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        return http.getSharedObject(AuthenticationManagerBuilder.class)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationEventPublisher authenticationEventPublisher
            (ApplicationEventPublisher applicationEventPublisher) {
        return new DefaultAuthenticationEventPublisher(applicationEventPublisher);
    }
}
```

**BUT** when I use:

```
http.authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers("/**")
    .permitAll()
    .anyRequest()
    .authenticated()
    .and()
    .csrf()
    .disable();
```

It works, but I want that user should be authorized

**Keycloak Client settings:**
[image: keycloak-settings]

**pom.xml:**

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
            <artifactId>keycloak-core</artifactId>
            <version>22.0.4</version>
        </dependency>
```

**appiclation.properties:**

```
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.keycloak.client-id=work-app
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.keycloak.authorization-grant-type=authorization_code
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.keycloak.scope=openid
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.keycloak.issuer-uri=http://localhost:8080/realms/work
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.keycloak.user-name-attribute=preferred_username
spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.issuer-uri=http://localhost:8080/realms/work
```